# ItemsTemplate in Listview not showing via Page.Resources

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

Can anyone help me. I'm trying to show a listview in a content dialog box. 
Ultimately, I'll be using Bindings but for troubleshooting I just want to see a textbox with the word "test" in it. Here's some code:

MainPage.xaml

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyUploadsDialogTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <RelativePanel>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="MyArtistTextBox" Width="150" TextAlignment="Center" Text="TEST" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>


                </RelativePanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then I have a class for my contentdialogbox:

```
class MyUploadsDialog
{
    public static ListView MyUploadsListView = new ListView() { Height = 375, Width = 410, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 48, 179, 221)) };

    public static Panel MyUploadsPanel = new StackPanel();
    public static ContentDialog UploadsDialog = new ContentDialog() { Title = "My Music Uploads" };

    //Constructor
    public MyUploadsDialog()
    {

        Initialize();

    }
    public void Initialize()
    {


        MyUploadsPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "As an artist or label, you will see you music uploads here with some basic info about them.",
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
        });



        MyUploadsPanel.Children.Add(MyUploadsListView);

        UploadsDialog.Content = MyUploadsPanel;

        UploadsDialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Close";
        UploadsDialog.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true;

    }
}
```

Finally, I assign the page.resources DataTemplate to the ListView.ItemTemplate in my MainPage() Constructor:

```
MyUploadsDialog.MyUploadsListView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["MyUploadsDialogTemplate"];
```

The result is that I see the blue ListView background... But I do not see the TextBox with the word "test" inside the Listview.

I dont get any errors or exceptions, it just wont show the DataTemplate code.

Any help would be great.

UPDATE: my typical listview in XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="NewMusicListView"  Height="275" Width="410" Margin="20,0,0,0" RelativePanel.RightOf="MusicCountBox" RelativePanel.Below="Blurb" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="NewMusicListView_SelectionChanged">

                    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <RelativePanel>

                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArtistHeader" Padding="25,0,0,0" Width="150" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Artist Name" FontSize="18" Foreground="#ff6600"></TextBlock>


                                        <TextBlock x:Name="SongHeader"   Padding="25,0,0,0" Width="150" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Song Title" RelativePanel.RightOf="ArtistHeader" FontSize="18" Foreground="#ff6600"></TextBlock>
                                    </RelativePanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel>
                                <RelativePanel>

                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArtistTextBox" Width="150" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Artist}" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="SongTextBox" Width="150" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Song}" RelativePanel.RightOf="ArtistTextBox" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>


                                </RelativePanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Are there any items in your `ListView`? Have you assigned the `ListView.ItemsSource`?

Comment: I updated the post... see the update... I never use ItemSource.. but then again, I never programatically have to make a listview...

Comment: Your `ListView` doesn't have any items in it. You have to assign `ItemsSource`, otherwise it will remain empty.

Comment: How would I do that... because... I'm adding the item in my DataTemplate Resource... is that not correct?

Comment: No, you are just editing DataTemplate for ListView ITEM, so if you add 2 ITEMs to list view, they will have this DataTemplate set (each one of them) containing the Item you added there. ITEM - ListView item, Item - part of the DataTemplate of the ITEM.

Comment: So I just need to add the two items I need.
like this?
items.add(acontrol)
items.add(another);
listview.itemsource = items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. thanks for your help guys. I've been working so hard that my brain has simply gone to mush. I did use ItemsSource for my other listview bindings... So now that I have added that... It's working.

```
 MyUploadsListView.ItemsSource = MyUploadsList;
```

where the list is an observable collection.

thanks for your help!